# Add a tile behind a header image on Joomla site

Tags: joomla, tile

First post here.
I have a simple Joomla site that I need to add a tile behind a header image...
url("../images/trug-header-background-main.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center #10151C

Right now the color is behind...which I can easily change. The tile is an image that I've created.

Live working site: http://truglobal.org/dev/

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: what are you expecting exactly? could you explain better?

Comment: No problem. Replicating a wordpress site using a joomla template...existing site is here: http://theredumbrella.org/ basically a tiled image repeatng horizontally behind that header image. It's in a template css page. I was using firebug and can change the color, but cannot figure how to add a tile instead...

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take a look at your templates index.php - you can play around in there and add appropriate 'tiles', then use CSS to control them and their layout.